# How to send email with no-reply in spring-boot application

Tags: email, spring-boot

I'm trying to send emails to project managers whenever there is a change in their project staffing. For this i want to send an email from no-reply@example.com, how can i achieve this using spring boot?

Thanks in advance for the suggestions and answers.

Tried something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sendEmail", method = { RequestMethod.GET }, produces = { "application/json" })
    public ResponseEntity<CustomResponse> sendEmail() {

        LOG.debug("Start sendEmail with data, toAddress");

        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = commonUtil.setHeaders();

        HttpStatus httpStatus = HttpStatus.OK;

        CustomResponse customResp = new CustomResponse();

        String description;

        try {

            String to = "bmanikanta415@gmail.com";

            String from = "no-reply@example.com";

            Properties props = System.getProperties();

            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

            Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));

            msg.setSubject("Your Example.com account has been activated");

            msg.setText("This is a test");

            Transport.send(msg);

            description = Constants.SUCCESS;

            customResp = commonUtil.getCustomResponse(httpStatus, description, description);

        } catch (

        Exception e) {

            LOG.error("Exception in sendEmail: {}", e);

            description = Constants.FAILED;

            customResp = commonUtil.getCustomResponse(httpStatus, description, description);

        }

        ResponseEntity<CustomResponse> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<CustomResponse>(customResp, httpHeaders,
                httpStatus);

        LOG.debug("End sendEmail with return data: {}", responseEntity);

        return responseEntity;

    }
```

Comment: see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-email and https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/09/testing-mail-code-in-spring-boot-application.html

Comment: Thanks for the response, i went through https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/09/testing-mail-code-in-spring-boot-application.html, but i want to send emails to gmail account, that's not happening in this case...

Comment: ensure that less security app in enabled on the mail id from which you want to send an emal.

Comment: Yeahh, its enabled before itself, but the mails are in fake smtp server only....